# Unity on WP8 - Saving Screenshot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, screenshot

i have a unity background (some animated object) with some controls (pivot control) on top of it (in my wp8 solution).
Now i want to save the unity background to an writable BitmapImage, but all i get as an result is a black background.
Here is my layout:

```
<DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid x:Name="DrawingSurfaceBackground" 
        Loaded="DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded" Visibility="Visible">

    <Grid x:Name="Weather_Grid" Visibility="Visible">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
[...]
```

So my rootgrid is DrawingSurfaceBackground.
I am saving the image like this:

```
internal void SetBackgroundImage(System.Windows.Controls.DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid DrawingSurfaceBackground)
{
    WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(DrawingSurfaceBackground, null);
    wbmp.Invalidate();
    Settings.Instance.BackgroundImage = wbmp;
}
```

So nothing special about it. 
Can you tell me why im only getting a black image?

Maybe its not possible to save the unity background?

Thanks in advance.

robidd

Comment: I have no experience in with Windows Phone 8 and Unity, but you will definitely be able to capture the Unity background using a Unity function like [Application.CaptureScreenshot](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html).

Comment: thanks that worked!
i am saving the image via 
   Application.CaptureScreenshot(Application.persistentDataPath + @"/background.png");
and loading it from my wp8 project!